Gabriela Mistral's La pajita
La pajita is another poem from Gabriela Mistral's second collection Ternura ("Tenderness") that uses simple language without necessarily being easy to interpret.
On the surface, it is about visual perception that gets distorted when a bit of straw flies in someone's eye, but is that all there is to it? The same thing is successively seen as a waxen doll, a bit of straw, a type of flower, a ray of sun on the windowpane and lastly a bit of straw. Is there a connection between these "images"? Why "little eyes" ("ojitos") instead of just "eyes" at the end of the first stanza? What does the "real party" or "true festival" in the last line refer to? And why would the poem's speaker lose it entirely?

Below is a fairly literal translation of the poem.

The straw
This one was a waxwork girl/doll;
but she was not a wax girl/doll,
she was a sheaf standing on the threshing floor.
But she was not a sheaf
but the stiff flower of the sunflower.
Nor was it the flower, but it was
a ray of sun glued to the window.
It wasn't even a ray of sunshine:
a straw was inside my little eyes.
Just look at how I've lost everything / entirely,
in this tearfulness, my real party!


Spanish uses lots of diminuitives, it's "tender", which is what the poem comes under.  Also ojitos matches pajita. Both small.

@Lambie There is no need to point out that Spanish uses diminutives; I know enough Spanish to recognise them in the original text. My native language also uses diminutives; I am thoroughly familiar with the concept.

You asked: Why "little eyes" ("ojitos") instead of just "eyes" . How would you make the point I did? Just not make it? Not mention diminuitives? Or just say: ojitos matches pajitas? There is also a sound thing: una pajita dentro de mis ojos, is not as cutsey ("tender") as una pajita dentro de mis ojitos era.  three syllables with t sounds in the third syllable.

Both this poem "La pajita", and "La rata" asked about in a separate question, are found in the same section of Tenura, namely in "Jugarretas". This is a word that is hard to translate. It can mean a trick or a game, and here it refers to the verbal tricks used in the poems here.
The title of the book, Ternura means "Tenderness", which contrasts with Mistral's first collection Desolacíon. Accordingly it is more optimistic, and particularly deals with the love between a mother and a child. The work contains lullabies and cradle-songs, the tricks ("jugarretas"), and short stories. In an interview in 19451, Mistral said that "La pajita" was actually her favourite work:

It may seem strange to you, but among all my works, the one I prefer
is a little lullaby ("canción de cuna") that I wrote with the title "La pajita". It must
be because I feel a deep affection for this kind of poetry.

Mistral was a schoolteacher for much of her life, and she detested childishness and condescension in works aimed at children2. So even though the jugarretas are aimed at children, they are written in a deceptively sophisticated way. In a public lecture3 in 1938 Mistral discussed this poem, saying:

Voy a decirles esa pequeña poesía que habla de la viga en el ojito del
niño. ... está escrita en la  lengua folklórica de nuestro pueblo
chileno que cuenta de una curiosa  manera diciendo: esta que o este
que.

I translate this as:

I am going to tell you about this little poem that talks about the
beam in the child’s eye... it is written in the folk language of our
Chilean people, which tells in a curious way saying: esta que o este
que.

The "beam in the eye" refers to the Biblical phrase "the mote and the beam", which in Spanish becomes "the beam and the straw" ("la viga y la pajita").
I have left the last phrase untranslated, because it is the basis of the joke/trick in the poem: confusion over the subject of a verb. In Spanish, as in Latin, pronouns are rarely used except for emphasis, and so "era" may mean "he is", "she is", or "it is".
The first few lines of the poem read:

Esta que era una niña de cera;
pero no era una niña de cera,
era una gavilla parada en la era.
Pero no era una gavilla
sino la flor tiesa de la maravilla.

This seems straightforward, the first line reads "This was little girl made of wax". We could read the second line as contradicting this "But she was a not a little wax girl", but that would be falling into the trick. We do not know what the subject of the second verb is, it is just a lazy assumption that it is the same as in the first line. If we instead read it as "he", then the second and third lines can be read us "But this [pointing at someone else] was not a wax girl, he was a wheat-sheaf standing where the wheat is threshed". This could be written unambiguously as "Este que no era..." to contrast with the first line's "Esta que era...". Note that this is exactly the clue that Mistral gave in her talk: the importance of distinguishing between "esta" (femenine) and "este" (masculine).
At this point we also have a pun. The word "era" has been repeated four times so far, but while the first times it was a verbal form of ser ("to be"), in the final instance it is the noun "la era" meaning "a threshing floor". The "gavilla" ("wheatsheaf"), needed to make sense of the threshing floor, is then rhymed with "maravilla", "un flor de maravilla" literally meaning "a flower of wonder", but here being a Chilean idiom for a sunflower.
The joy of the poem is in these confusions between the subjects of verbs which mislead and lose the reader at first glance, the puns, the repetition and the rhymes, and is essentially untranslatable.
In short, there is no point looking for deep meanings in the text. Reading it is a game or a trick, and a matter of enjoying the verbal fireworks. Unfortunately these are extremely hard to explain without killing the joy of reading it.


Interview with Gabriela Mistral, EI Mercurio, Santiago, November 1945.
"Gabriela Mistral: Algunas referencias a Ternura", Jaime Quezada, Acta Literaria No 14, 1989.
Public lecture, Teatro Caupolicán, Santiago, May 1938.


era is not a threshing floor as that would be inside a barn or structure. It's just a firm area of beaten earth where threshing takes place. And pajita here in English would be a mote. a straw was inside my little eyes. is really: a mote in my little eyes.

@Lambie: Use Google Image Search to look for "threshing floor". Almost all the results you get are outside.

@PeterShor In the RAE, it says this for era, meaning 2: 1. f. Espacio de tierra limpia y firme, algunas veces empedrado, donde se trillan las mieses.  A space made of clean, firm earth, sometimes covered with rocks, where crops are threshed.

@Lambie: Exactly! What I'm saying is that this is very similar to the English definition of a threshing floor. From Wikipedia: A threshing floor is of two main types: 1) a specially flattened outdoor surface, usually circular and paved, or 2) inside a building with a smooth floor of earth, stone or wood. Unless you insist on translating it as an outdoors threshing floor, the phrase threshing floor is as good a translation of era as you're going to get.

https://vafweb.wildapricot.org/widget/page-1821609/3796149 threshing ground can also be inside. I prefer threshing ground.//A threshing floor is of two main types: 1) a specially flattened outdoor surface, usually circular and paved,[2] or 2) inside a building with a smooth floor of earth, stone or wood where a farmer would thresh the grain harvest and then winnow it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshing_floor

So just to make sure I understand, the second meaning of the second and third lines is "It wasn't a wax girl that was standing on the threshing floor, it was a sheaf"? This poem is thus almost impossible to translate properly. I'm not sure I understand why Le Guin bothered.

Esta que era una niña de cera;
pero no era una niña de cera,
era una gavilla parada en la era. This one who was a wax girl but was not a wax girl, She or It was a sheaf upright on the earthen threshing ground. In LA, threshing is more apt to be done outside, not inside. and in Chile, the earth is often quasi "threshing ready"  Clara mentioned that we can't say for sure what the subject is: it or she.

@PeterShor I'd say it's impossible to translate while preserving the trick. I can't think of an English form that would retain the deliberate ambiguity of the Spanish lines.

See the outside threshing ground in Chile: https://www.britannica.com/video/traditions-village-Chilean/-194814

@ClaraDíazSanchez: This is off-topic, but here is an English poem with a similar, but different trick:
"I Saw a Peacock, with a fiery tail, //
I saw a Blazing Comet, drop down hail, //
I saw a Cloud, with Ivy circled round, //
I saw a sturdy Oak, creep on the ground, ..."

@PeterShor Yes, it's a similar idea: a text that looks like nonsense until you crack the code, and then it all falls apart.
